# C++ How works set of function's argument value?

Tags: c++, variables

I am learning C++ and I have code:

```
float x, y;

namespace X {
    void SetMyX(float p) {
        x = p;
    }
    void SetMyY(float p) {
        y = p;
    }
    namespace XY {
        void Set(float p = 0.0f) {
            x = p;
            p = y;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    X::SetMyX(5.4f);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    X::SetMyY(4.1f);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    X::XY::Set();
    std::cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And output is:

```
x = 5.4 y = 0
x = 5.4 y = 4.1
x = 0 y = 4.1
```

And I figure out variable `p`  sets value of `x`  and then `y`  sets value of  `p`? But, how it is possible? In C++ you can also set value of function's argument or what?
It's just weird for me because I thought you can't just "editing" entered value and you must add another variable like result or something like that, or just return sum of two arguments, but change them?

Comment: If your arguments are not const, you can assign any value to it like any other variables. The only thing is that at the end of the function arguments will be destroy anyway. So setting p with value of y does nothing in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the argument `p` is a completely normal variable and you can do everything with it.

This will also work in many other languages like C, Java, Javascript or Python.